# How to deal with missing bars in stocks data?

Tags: stock, algorithmic-trading, trading

I have stocks data with a time frame of 1 minute (coming from Alpaca). Basically, it looks like this, with dummy values:

| symbol | minute | open | high | low | close | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 1 | 100 | 101 | 99 | 100 | 1000 |
| AAPL | 2 | 100 | 101 | 99 | 100 | 1000 |
| AAPL | 3 | None | None | None | None | None |
| AAPL | 4 | 100 | 101 | 99 | 100 | 1000 |
| APPL | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I was surprised to see that it is possible to have missing data as in row 3.

Here are my questions:

- Does this happen because there was no share traded during that time frame (minute 3 in the example)?
- Does it mean that the volume is equal to 0 during that time frame ? In that case, I could replace None by 0 for the volume at minute 3
- If no share was traded, it means the price was constant during the time frame. So, is it correct to say that open = 100, high = 100, low = 100, close = 100?

If all that is correct, I could fill in the None values and remove them entirely.

Let me know! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure

but I think, there is no trade, so there is no bar

close price is the same

volume is 0

high, low is close price

You can write what ever you want, but if the value is none, nothing happened